# Parse more json in the same html page with a jquery function

Tags: jquery, json, html, parsing

Hi i have a problem with a web application. In a html page i have two o more json (that are the result of a php page) and with a jquery function i have to parse them.
The problem is that if in the page there is only one json for the parsing there aren't problem but if there are two or more json it doesn't work. Which is the problem?
Someone can help me?
These are two example of json :

```
{"Nr SAT":"SAT000000002574","Tipo Servizio":"GR","Stato":"ciao","Attributo":"APERTURA SAT SU IMEI DUPLICATO","Marca":"LG","Modello":"U830","Modello Guasto":"353142010979931"}
        {"Nr SAT":"SAT000000002574","Tipo Servizio":"Vedi anche me","Stato":"ahhhhhhhhhhhhh","Attributo":"APERTURA SAT SU IMEI DUPLICATO","Marca":"LG","Modello":"U830","Modello Guasto":"353142010979931"}
```

These is the jquery function that i use for the parsing:

```
<script>

        $.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 
            $('body').append($('<p>').html('Tipo di Servizio: '+ data["Tipo Servizio"]));
        });
        $.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 
            $('body').append($('<p>').html('Stato: '+ data["Stato"]));
        });

        $.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 
            $('body').append($('<p>').html('Nr SAT: '+ data["Nr SAT"]));
        });
        $.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 
            $('body').append($('<p>').html('Attributo: '+ data["Attributo"]));
        });
        $.getJSON('http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) { 
            $('body').append($('<p>').html('Marca: '+ data["Marca"]));
        });
    </script>
```

This is the php that generate the  json.
If in the control "if ($line_of_text[0] == "SAT000000002574")" i have more of one result in which way i can generate a json in the correct format???

```
<?php

  // Sopprimo gli errori del php
  error_reporting(0);

  // Includo la libreria
  require_once 'excel_reader2.php';

  //Recupero il valore del parametro "nome"

    $file_handle = fopen("leggimi2.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {


$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);


    if ($line_of_text[0] == "SAT000000002574")
    {
        //print $line_of_text[0]." ".$line_of_text[1]." ".$line_of_text[2]." ".$line_of_text[3]." ".$line_of_text[4]." ".$line_of_text[5]." ".$line_of_text[6]." ".$line_of_text[7];


        $arr = array('Nr SAT' => $line_of_text[0], 'Tipo Servizio' => $line_of_text[1], 'Stato' => $line_of_text[2], 'Attributo' => $line_of_text[3], 'Marca' => $line_of_text[4], 'Modello' => $line_of_text[5], 
                'Modello Guasto' => $line_of_text[6]);


    echo json_encode($arr);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to focus on:

First, in your JS code, you're making an ajax call for every item in the same object. You're requesting the same data multiple times which is unnecessary. You should pack all the append commands into a single `getJSON` call.

Second, when you have multiple lines in your excel file, you are echoing multiple objects one after another, which produces invalid JSON. You should organize them into a single JSON array, and loop through it in your `getJSON` callback.

Here is the code:

**PHP**

```
<?php

// Sopprimo gli errori del php
error_reporting(0);

// Includo la libreria
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';

//Recupero il valore del parametro "nome"

$file_handle = fopen("leggimi2.csv", "r");

//EDIT: Define an array to hold individual lines
$data = array();

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    if ($line_of_text[0] == "SAT000000002574")
    {
        $arr = array('Nr SAT' => $line_of_text[0], 'Tipo Servizio' => $line_of_text[1], 'Stato' => $line_of_text[2], 'Attributo' => $line_of_text[3], 'Marca' => $line_of_text[4], 'Modello' => $line_of_text[5], 'Modello Guasto' => $line_of_text[6]);

        //EDIT: Add the line to the array
        $data[] = $arr;
    }
}

//EDIT: Encode the array as a JSON array of line objects
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now, what returns to your `getJSON` call is an array of objects.

**JS**

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, 
    function(data) {
        // 'data' is an array of objects here
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            //data[i] is an individual line of excel data
            $('body')
                .append($('<p>').html('Tipo di Servizio: '+ data[i]["Tipo Servizio"]))
                .append($('<p>').html('Stato: '+ data[i]["Stato"]))
                .append($('<p>').html('Nr SAT: '+ data[i]["Nr SAT"]))
                .append($('<p>').html('Attributo: '+ data[i]["Attributo"]))
                .append($('<p>').html('Marca: '+ data[i]["Marca"]));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON seems uncorrect. You should return a JSON code like:

```
[
  {"Nr SAT":"SAT000000002574",
   "Tipo Servizio":"GR",
    "Stato":"ciao",
   "Attributo":"APERTURA SAT SU IMEI DUPLICATO",
   "Marca":"LG","Modello":"U830", 
    "Modello Guasto":"353142010979931"
   },
   {"Nr SAT":"SAT000000002574",
   "Tipo Servizio":"Vedi anche me",
   "Stato":"ahhhhhhhhhhhhh",
   "Attributo":"APERTURA SAT SU IMEI DUPLICATO",
    "Marca":"LG", "Modello":"U830",
   "Modello Guasto":"353142010979931"
   }
]
```

Remember to insert the values in an array.
And you should use a validator like http://jsonlint.com/

PS: ciao, e speriamo che funzioni;)